# What difference do we have between almost everywhere convergence and convergence in $L^1$ norm?

Tags: integration, measure-theory, convergence-divergence, lebesgue-integral

let $(X, \Sigma, \mu)$ be a measure space

$f_n \to f$ in   $L^1$ norm  means that : $f_n \in L^1$ for ever $n$ and $\int_X |f_n-f|d\mu \to 0$

almost everywhere convergence  means that $f_n \to f$ pointwise except for a set of points $J$ which is negligible. meaning $\mu(J) = 0$

> I'm still new to measure theory and I'd like to know what's in common or different beteween these two notions ? also if one implies the other or vice versa.

thanks !

Comment: you have already give the difference what else do you need

Comment: He asks if one implies the other. And the answer is no. We only need to come with counter-examples.

Comment: mostly if one of them implies the other or not.

Comment: In general, neither implies the other. If there is a $c > 0$ such that $\mu(J) < c \implies \mu(J) = 0$, then $L^1$-convergence implies convergence a.e.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have already give the difference However there some couples of implication to each other

**First** if the convergence in norm holds true **then the converseof the Lebesgue  Convergence Dominated theorem** says there is exist a subsequence $(f_{n_j})_j$ of $(f_n)_n$ that convergence almost everywhere to $f$

**Second** if the convergence almost everywhere holds true  and there exists a function $g\in L^1$ such that $|f_n|\le g$ almost everywhere then 
**The Lebesgue Convergence dominated theorem** says the convergence in norm holds true too.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f_n = 2^n \cdot 1_{\left(\frac{1}{2^n}, \frac{1}{2^{n-1}}\right]}$, $f_n$ pointwise converge to $f \equiv 0$. But $\int |f_n - f| d\mu = 1$, so no convergence in $L^1$.